# Получить список расположения компьютеров в AD

Tags: powershell

у меня есть список компьютеров в текстовом файле мне нужно каждому компьютеру добавить местоположение в AD.
К примеру вот так будет выглядеть скрипт отображения местоположения в AD для одного компьютера:

`get-adcomputer -identity comp1 | FT Name, DistinguishedName`.

Но как загрузить список из файла в powershell, а потом пройтись по нему?

Comment: Типа `foreach ($i in (Get-Content complist.txt )) {get-adcomputer -identity $i|FT name,DistinguishedName} ` ?

Comment: @Daemon-5 работает, спасибо. Оформи в виде ответа